# Strange Behaviour of Hook Script commit-mime-type-check.pl on windows

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I have downloaded pre-commit hook script "commit-mime-type-check.pl" from [svn.apache.org](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/check-mime-type.pl?revision=867034&view=co)
I am working on windows there are only two things to change path to svnlook binary and path to temp dir.I did that. but I am getting following error

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: '-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  
Error: operable program or batch file.  
Error: C:\vsvn\Repositories\myproj\hooks\local_commit_mime_eol_check.pl:   
Error: `C:\vsvn\bin\svnlook.exe changed C:\vsvn\Repositories\myproj -t 16-1l' failed   
Error: with no output.  
Finished!:
```

I debugged by self and found where it is getting failed.

```
my $pid = open(SAFE_READ, '-|');
```

I read the explanation on about open with "-|" on [_http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC] under safe pipe Open

> Safe Pipe Opens
>   Another interesting approach to IPC is making your single program go multiprocess and communicate between--or even amongst--yourselves. The open() function will accept a file argument of either "-|" or "|-" to do a very interesting thing: it forks a child connected to the filehandle you've opened. The child is running the same program as the parent. This is useful for safely opening a file when running under an assumed UID or GID, for example. If you open a pipe to minus, you can write to the filehandle you opened and your kid will find it in his STDIN. If you open a pipe from minus, you can read from the filehandle you opened whatever your kid writes to his STDOUT.

**What I am not able to understand it is due to non-compatibility or what. As it is originally was written on linux box and that is very rich for piping and intern process communication. where I always find window poor.(No offence to anyone. this is my personal feeling. Lets get back to the topic. I am looking for all the wild suggestions. Not seeking for fix but if I get, I would appreciate**

I tried everything but failed at last I tried to google about this to if someone is also facing the same issue. not many links but found [this one](http://jasig.275507.n4.nabble.com/pre-commit-hook-re-svn-mime-type-preventing-commit-td1572805.html) and interesting part is this, it is unresolved. Then I have no way but ask here.

Below is the script code for your reference

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# ====================================================================
# commit-mime-type-check.pl: check that every added file has the
# svn:mime-type property set and every added file with a mime-type
# matching text/* also has svn:eol-style set. If any file fails this
# test the user is sent a verbose error message suggesting solutions and
# the commit is aborted.
#
# Usage: commit-mime-type-check.pl REPOS TXN-NAME
# ====================================================================
# Most of commit-mime-type-check.pl was taken from
# commit-access-control.pl, Revision 9986, 2004-06-14 16:29:22 -0400.
# ====================================================================
# Copyright (c) 2000-2004 CollabNet.  All rights reserved.
#
# This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
# you should have received as part of this distribution.  The terms
# are also available at http://subversion.tigris.org/license.html.
# If newer versions of this license are posted there, you may use a
# newer version instead, at your option.
#
# This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
# individuals.  For exact contribution history, see the revision
# history and logs, available at http://subversion.tigris.org/.
# ====================================================================

# Turn on warnings the best way depending on the Perl version.
BEGIN {
  if ( $] >= 5.006_000)
    { require warnings; import warnings; }
  else
    { $^W = 1; }
}

use strict;
use Carp;


######################################################################
# Configuration section.

# Svnlook path.
my $svnlook = "/usr/bin/svnlook";

# Since the path to svnlook depends upon the local installation
# preferences, check that the required program exists to insure that
# the administrator has set up the script properly.
{
  my $ok = 1;
  foreach my $program ($svnlook)
    {
      if (-e $program)
        {
          unless (-x $program)
            {
              warn "$0: required program `$program' is not executable, ",
                   "edit $0.\n";
              $ok = 0;
            }
        }
      else
        {
          warn "$0: required program `$program' does not exist, edit $0.\n";
          $ok = 0;
        }
    }
  exit 1 unless $ok;
}

######################################################################
# Initial setup/command-line handling.

&usage unless @ARGV == 2;

my $repos        = shift;
my $txn          = shift;

unless (-e $repos)
  {
    &usage("$0: repository directory `$repos' does not exist.");
  }
unless (-d $repos)
  {
    &usage("$0: repository directory `$repos' is not a directory.");
  }

# Define two constant subroutines to stand for read-only or read-write
# access to the repository.
sub ACCESS_READ_ONLY  () { 'read-only' }
sub ACCESS_READ_WRITE () { 'read-write' }


######################################################################
# Harvest data using svnlook.

# Change into /tmp so that svnlook diff can create its .svnlook
# directory.
my $tmp_dir = '/tmp';
chdir($tmp_dir)
  or die "$0: cannot chdir `$tmp_dir': $!\n";

# Figure out what files have added using svnlook.
my @files_added;
foreach my $line (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'changed', $repos, '-t', $txn))
  {
        # Add only files that were added to @files_added
    if ($line =~ /^A.  (.*[^\/])$/)
      {
        push(@files_added, $1);
      }
  }

my @errors;
foreach my $path ( @files_added )
    {
        my $mime_type;
        my $eol_style;

        # Parse the complete list of property values of the file $path to extract
        # the mime-type and eol-style
        foreach my $prop (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'proplist', $repos, '-t',
                          $txn, '--verbose', $path))
            {
                if ($prop =~ /^\s*svn:mime-type : (\S+)/)
                    {
                        $mime_type = $1;
                    }
                elsif ($prop =~ /^\s*svn:eol-style : (\S+)/)
                    {
                        $eol_style = $1;
                    }
            }

        # Detect error conditions and add them to @errors
        if (not $mime_type)
            {
                push @errors, "$path : svn:mime-type is not set";
            }
        elsif ($mime_type =~ /^text\// and not $eol_style)
            {
                push @errors, "$path : svn:mime-type=$mime_type but svn:eol-style is not set";
            }
    }

# If there are any errors list the problem files and give information
# on how to avoid the problem. Hopefully people will set up auto-props
# and will not see this verbose message more than once.
if (@errors)
  {
    warn "$0:\n\n",
         join("\n", @errors), "\n\n",
                 <<EOS;

    Every added file must have the svn:mime-type property set. In
    addition text files must have the svn:eol-style property set.

    For binary files try running
    svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream path/of/file

    For text files try
    svn propset svn:mime-type text/plain path/of/file
    svn propset svn:eol-style native path/of/file

    You may want to consider uncommenting the auto-props section
    in your ~/.subversion/config file. Read the Subversion book
    (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), Chapter 7, Properties section,
    Automatic Property Setting subsection for more help.
EOS
    exit 1;
  }
else
  {
    exit 0;
  }

sub usage
{
  warn "@_\n" if @_;
  die "usage: $0 REPOS TXN-NAME\n";
}

sub safe_read_from_pipe
{
  unless (@_)
    {
      croak "$0: safe_read_from_pipe passed no arguments.\n";
    }
  print "Running @_\n";
  my $pid = open(SAFE_READ, '-|');
  unless (defined $pid)
    {
      die "$0: cannot fork: $!\n";
    }
  unless ($pid)
    {
      open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT")
        or die "$0: cannot dup STDOUT: $!\n";
      exec(@_)
        or die "$0: cannot exec `@_': $!\n";
    }
  my @output;
  while (<SAFE_READ>)
    {
      chomp;
      push(@output, $_);
    }
  close(SAFE_READ);
  my $result = $?;
  my $exit   = $result >> 8;
  my $signal = $result & 127;
  my $cd     = $result & 128 ? "with core dump" : "";
  if ($signal or $cd)
    {
      warn "$0: pipe from `@_' failed $cd: exit=$exit signal=$signal\n";
    }
  if (wantarray)
    {
      return ($result, @output);
    }
  else
    {
      return $result;
    }
}

sub read_from_process
  {
  unless (@_)
    {
      croak "$0: read_from_process passed no arguments.\n";
    }
  my ($status, @output) = &safe_read_from_pipe(@_);
  if ($status)
    {
      if (@output)
        {
          die "$0: `@_' failed with this output:\n", join("\n", @output), "\n";
        }
      else
        {
          die "$0: `@_' failed with no output.\n";
        }
    }
  else
    {
      return @output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep looking at this Perl syntax, and I say to myself, "*Wow, this is old*".

If you look at the Perldoc of the [open function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), you'll see that the two parameter argument doesn't mention what your hook script is doing. Yet, as you pointed out, perlipc does mention it.

What it looks like is that your Perl interpreter is interpreting `|-` as mentioned in the Perldoc open funcition description:

- This is a two parameter form of the function. Thus:

  - The first argument is the name of the file handle.
  - The second argument is the name of the file.
- Since the file name ends with a pipe, the rest of the file name is the name of the command to execute which to pipe though STDIN when you read from the pipe.

Since the second argument is `-|`, it's looking for a command called `-`. No such command named `-`, the `open` function fails.

Not sure what you can do, but you can borrow my [Pre-commit Kitchen Sink Hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/svn-hooks.zip) which can do a whole variety of things.

One of the things it can do is enforce property types and values based upon file names. For example, you can force all files that end with the `.sh` suffix to have `svn:eol-type` to be `LF`, or that files with the `.pdf` suffix have `svn:mime-type` set to `application/pdf` which is what I believe what this hook is suppose to do.

I'll go through this hook script a bit more to see if I can wrangle out exactly what it's doing and how it works. I'd submit a *fixed* version of the hookscript to Apache, but they're not maintaining hook scripts anymore.

I've never used the `open SAFE_READ, "-|"` syntax before but you learn something every day. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: Apparently, this is a Perlism to fork a process. When that happens, the child and parent have the same environment (except for the `$pid` and are executing the same line in the Perl script. Windows doesn't fork, so this won't work on Windows.